# QTest mouseClick on a QPushButton

Tags: qt, qtestlib

i tried to click a QPushButton with the mouseClick function of the QTest namespace. 
The QPushButton is a private Member of an Widget. The position of the mouse cursor during the click is in the center of the button, but the Button is not clicked... 
Can somebady explain me why?

```
MyWidget *myWidget= new myWidget();

myWidget->show();

while ( !myWidget->isVisible() ) {
     QTest::qWait(200);
}

QTest::qWait(500);
QTest::mouseMove ( myWidget, QPoint( 70, 100 ), -1 );
QTest::mouseClick ( myWidget, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier, QPoint( 70, 100 ), 100);
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the reason is that you send the mouse event to the parent widget and not to the button itself?

Comment: The problem is that the button is a private member of the widget so I don't get access on it.

Comment: Well, what if you try to find your button by calling: `QWidget *btn = myWidget->childAt(70, 100);` and than invoke mouse click on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the comment to be the answer.

The possible reason for the problem is that you send the mouse event to the parent widget rather then to the button itself. What if you try to find your button by using `QWidget::childAt()` function? For example:

```
[..]
QTest::mouseMove ( myWidget, QPoint( 70, 100 ), -1 );
QWidget *btn = myWidget->childAt(70, 100);
if (btn) {
    QTest::mouseClick ( btn, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier, QPoint( 70, 100 ), 100);
}
```