# Qt: Simulate QMouseButtonPress events from top parent widget

Tags: c++, qt

I use a QWidget as top window with some child widgets in it. For testing purposes, I want to simulate MouseButtonPress events, by only specifying the x/y coordinates of the mouse click.

In the top window, I run this code:

```
QMouseEvent* evt = new QMouseEvent(
    QEvent::MouseButtonPress,
    QPointF(x_coord,y_coord),
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::LeftButton,
    0);
// topWindow is a pointer to the top window QWidget
QApplication::postEvent(topWindow, evt);
```

x_coord and y_coord are the coordinates local to the top window, I recorded them previously.

I have an event filter installed through `app.installEventFilter(&eventFilter);`
and I can see the event being posted, however, the event never gets propagated to the children widgets
of the top window. I assume, this is because I specify 'topWindow' as receiving object for the event and the object cannot propagate the event "down" to its children (but could only propagate them up to its parents, if there were any).

Important for my purpose is that I can generate the mouse events centralized in the top window and I
don't want to maintain a list of pointers for each and every child object in the top window (there are of course multiple hierarchies of widgets).

How can I post the event so that it gets sent to the object at x_coord/y_coord without knowing the pointer to that object?

Answer (score 0):

I found one answer here: [QTest mouseClick on a QPushButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394236/qtest-mouseclick-on-a-qpushbutton#)

Essentially, the event cannot be sent to the topWindow, but needs to be sent to the correct child widget at the x_coord/y_coord position. The child widget can be found with this function:

```
QWidget *child = win->childAt( x_coord , y_coord );
QApplication::postEvent(topWindow, evt);
```